# Insert all when invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I am trying to implement an Insert All When query. I keep getting invalid identifier error and I'm not sure if its my table structure of my discount table causing the error or if I should be including something else in my query.

CUSTOMER TABLE

```
Name       Type         
C_ID    NUMBER       
C_FN    VARCHAR2(10) 
C_LN    VARCHAR2(10) 
C_PH    VARCHAR2(12)    
C_BD    DATE
```

DISCOUNT TABLE

```
Name Type         
C_ID  NUMBER       
C_LN  VARCHAR2(10) 
C_FN  VARCHAR2(10)
```

My Query:

```
INSERT ALL
   WHEN C_BD <= TO_DATE('01-JAN-1950','DD-MON-YYYY') THEN
     INTO DISCOUNT(C_ID,C_LN,C_FN)
     VALUES(C_ID,C_LN,C_FN)
SELECT C_ID,C_LN,FROM CUSTOMER;
```

C_BD is throwing the error by being an 'invalid identifier'

I want to understand what is causing this problem

Comment: missing a column name there? `SELECT C_ID,C_LN,FROM CUSTOMER`

Comment: Since you are only referencing a single table, perhaps `insert into discount select c_id, c_ln, c_fn from customer` would be better.  Either way, your problem is with your `select` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select `C_BD` in the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT ALL
   WHEN C_BD <= TO_DATE('01-JAN-1950', 'DD-MON-YYYY') THEN
       INTO DISCOUNT(C_ID,C_LN,C_FN)
       VALUES (C_ID, C_LN, C_FN)
   SELECT C_ID, C_LN, C_FN, C_BD
   FROM CUSTOMER;
```

Comment: So should C_BD be part of my discount's table structure?

Comment: @Injblue . . . It does not need to be.  The important point is that it is selected from `CUSTOMER` so it is visible to the `WHEN`.